# ASR-9K (vrf route and mgmt)

Tags: cisco-asr

I see that regular IOS & NX-OS & ASR(IOS-XE) have different ways of setting out-of-band management interface.

Below is brief config.

I can ping my immediate default gw but can't ping anything outside of my vlan/subnet.

Help appreciated, thanks!

#

#

```
RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:ios#show run
Tue Apr  4 16:17:55.079 UTC
Building configuration...
!! IOS XR Configuration 5.3.3
!! Last configuration change at Tue Apr  4 15:58:22 2017 by admin
!
vrf mgmt
!
interface MgmtEth0/RSP0/CPU0/0
 ipv4 address 10.7.0.38 255.255.255.0
!
interface MgmtEth0/RSP0/CPU0/1
 shutdown
!
!
router static
 address-family ipv4 unicast
  0.0.0.0/8 10.7.0.1
 !
 vrf mgmt
  address-family ipv4 unicast
   0.0.0.0/0 10.7.0.1
  !
```

#

#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your route:

```
0.0.0.0/8 10.7.0.1
```

should be

```
0.0.0.0/0 10.7.0.1
```